# How to properly generalize functions operating on vectors to those that operate on multi-dimensional arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I often end up implementing routines that operate on 1-D arrays, and then generalize them so that, if they are called on matrices, they treat each row independently.  For example, suppose we want a function that subtracts the mean of a vector from it, and then does that on every row of a matrix, if its input has more than one dimensions.  This can be implemented as follows:

```
import numpy as np

def _sub_mean(a):
    """ Subtract the mean from vector elements """

    assert isinstance(a, np.ndarray) and a.ndim == 1

    return a - np.mean(a)

def sub_mean(a):
    """ Subtract the mean

    If `a` is a 1D array it returns a 1D array (obtained by subtracting the
    mean of `a` from each of its elements).  If `a` has more than one dimension
    each row is treated separately

    """

    a = np.asanyarray(a)

    if a.ndim <= 1:
        a = np.atleast_1d(a)

        return np.squeeze(_sub_mean(a))

    retval = np.empty(a.shape)

    for idx in np.ndindex(*a.shape[:-1]):
        retval[idx] = _sub_mean(a[idx])

    return retval
```

Here are a few examples of the output of `sub_mean`:

```
>>> sub_mean(5)
array(0.)
>>> sub_mean([1, 2])
array([-0.5,  0.5])
>>> sub_mean([[1, 2], [4, 6]])
array([[-0.5,  0.5],
       [-1. ,  1. ]])
>>>
```

Note that the 'core' computation is taking place in the private function `_sub_mean`.  Indeed the same code in `sub_mean` can be used to generalize any function that operates on 1D arrays to one that operates on arbitrary number of dimensions, by replacing `_sub_mean`.  Also one can think of further generalization, for example adding an `axis` argument that specifies on which axis the function operates and/or possibility of operating on the flattened input array.

I was wondering if NumPy already provides a decorator to generalize functions that operate on vectors to those that operate on more-than-one-dimensional arrays?  I.e., if I can replace the above code by:

```
import numpy as np

@np.some_decorator
def sub_mean(a):        
    """ Subtract the mean

    If `a` is a 1D array it returns a 1D array (obtained by subtracting the
    mean of `a` from each of its elements).  If `a` has more than one dimension
    each row is treated separately  """


    assert isinstance(a, np.ndarray) and a.ndim == 1

    return a - np.mean(a)
```

(and, obviously, get the same outputs.)

---

UPDATE:  I ended up writing the following decorator:

```
class _Expand:
    def __init__(self, func1d):
        functools.update_wrapper(self, func1d)
        self._func1d = func1d

    def __call__(self, arr, *args, **kwargs):
        arr = np.asanyarray(arr)

        axis = kwargs.pop('axis', -1)

        return np.apply_along_axis(self._func1d, axis, arr, *args, **kwargs)
```

which would then enable me to write `sub_mean` (or any other complex function that operates on 1D arrays) as:

```
@_Expand
def sub_mean(a):        
    """ Subtract the mean

    If `a` is a 1D array it returns a 1D array (obtained by subtracting the
    mean of `a` from each of its elements).  If `a` has more than one dimension
    each row is treated separately  """


    assert isinstance(a, np.ndarray) and a.ndim == 1

    return a - np.mean(a)
```

(Note that `_Expand` allows to pick the axis along which the operation is performed --- that's slightly more generic than what I needed.)

Yet, I would still be curious to know if such a decorator is already implemented in NumPy?

Comment: Learn to use `axis`  and `keepdims` parameters and to use `broadcasting`.

Comment: @hpaulj do you mean `axis` and `keepdims` in `np.mean`?   Of course for this particular example I could  write `sub_mean` in a much more compact form using appropriate parameters in `np.mean`.  But this was only a MWE.   In my real problem I deal with a much more complicated 'core' function than `_sub_mean()`.

Comment: If you want any speed you have use features like that, from ground up.  Anything else results in python level iteration, including `np.apply_along_axis`

Comment: @hpaulj I totally understand. If the problem can be solved using built-in NumPy functions and those features the result is faster and cleaner.  But I repeat that here I used `mean` **just as an example**.  In my actual problem the function that works on 1D slice is much more complex.

Comment: But what are expecting or hoping `numpy` to do with your complex function?  Deconstruct it and rewriting using those whole-array features?  `numpy` does not apply introspection or compilation to user defined functions.  `numba` and `cython` are popular compilation tools.

Comment: @hpaulj Please see my update.  That would hopefully clarify what I was hoping NumPy to do.

Comment: I'm not aware of any `numpy` decorators.  Spend sometime looking at the code for `apply_along` and maybe run a few time tests.  It may be convenient when dealing with 3d arrays, but with 2d, you are just iterating on one axis, so it's overkill.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly common question, but has no perfect answer. The real answer is that you must end up tailoring each function individually.

Assuming you want to stick to pure numpy (and vanilla python) rather than using numba or cython, here are some considerations to keep in mind:

- [`np.apply_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) is implemented mostly as a python loop. It doesn't offer any real advantage besides a more compact notation.
- Almost all numpy functions accept an `axis` argument. As of numpy v1.15, you can supply a tuple multiple simultaneous axes to [ufuncs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html), and to many of the functions built on top of them.
- Ufuncs additionally have [methods](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#methods) that let you apply them at particular locations and combinations.
- Reduction functions, such as [`np.mean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) often have a `keepdims` argument. This allows you to combine reduction operations with the original array. Functions that don't support `keepdims` can be mitigated with manual axis insertion using, for example, [`np.expand_dims`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html).
- There are functions that perform operations specifically  on indices; most of their names start with `arg*`: [`np.nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html), [`np.argmin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html), [`np.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html), [`np.argpartition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html), [`np.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html), etc.

Taken together, you can vectorize almost any function that can be written for a single dimension. Sometimes the result requires extra cleverness, and sometimes it is outright impossible, but generally it is fairly simple. One example I can think of that is non-trivial is anything involving run-length encoding. The issue there is that you end up with a ragged array in some of the steps, requiring tools beyond numpy.

Your concrete example can be written as follows:

```
def sub_mean(a, axis):
    a = np.array(a, copy=False, subok=True)
    return a - np.mean(a, axis=axis, keepdims=True)
```

Comment: Interesting point about `np.apply_along_axis` being implemented mostly as a Python loop.  That probably explains why an equivalent of my `_Expand` decorator does not exist in NumPy.  It will not be an efficient solution.

Comment: @kMaster. Yup. I mostly summarized and broke down what hpaulj said. The rest is advice for specific cases. Unfortunately, unless you cythonize, numba complie, write C code or something similar, you can't vectorize totally arbitrary functions.